# Apache Flink: Merge two DataStreams with a CoFlatMapFunction

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to merge two streams of the same data type. I saw the `CoFlatMapfunction` and tried it out, but I'm getting the following error:

> "unspecified value parameters".

The code is written in Scala

```
val eventsTypeOne: DataStream[Option[Event]] =  patternStream1.select(pattern => selectFn1(pattern.toMap))
val eventsTypeTwo: DataStream[Option[Event]] = patternStream2.select(pattern => selectFn2(pattern.toMap))

eventsTypeOne.connect(eventsTypeTwo).flatMap(new CoFlatMapFunction[Option[Event], Option[Event], Option[Event]] {
  override def flatMap1(eventTypeOne: Option[Event], out: Collector[Option[Event]]): Unit = {
    out.collect(eventTypeOne)
  }

  override def flatMap2(eventTypeTwo: Option[Event], out: Collector[Option[Event]]): Unit = {
    out.collect(eventTypeTwo)
  }
})
}
```

How can I use the `CoFlatMapFunction` correctly? Or is there a more elegant way to merge two data streams?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess you program is not a valid Scala program. The line in with the error occurs would be interesting. You can achieve the same functionality by using a union().

Comment: thanks! The union function solved my problem

Comment: @twalthr, you should write you comment as an answer to the question ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve the same functionality by using a [`union()` operator](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/stream/operators/). Union allows to merge two streams of the same type.